# Sort an object by name

Tags: javascript, json, сортировка

Помогите отсортировать объекты в алфавитном порядке по полю `name`

```
var obj = {
    "Person1": {
        name: 'Max',
        age: 10
    },
    'Person2'': {
        name: 'John',
        age: 14
    },
    'Person3': {
        name: 'Anna',
        age: 20
    },
    'Person4': {
        name: 'Jim',
        age: 11
    }};
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас нет массива объектов, который можно было бы отсортировать. У вас есть значения полей `PersonN`, а понятие сортировки полей не существует. Два объекта, которые отличаются только порядком полей

```
const obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2};
const obj1 = {b: 2, a: 1};
```

считаются идентичными

Comment: @Drakonoved правильно говорит. Потому что при сравнении объектов сравниваются их адреса, а не содержимое. `{a: 1, b: 2} == {a: 1, b: 2}` тоже будет `false`. Объекты разные

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  "Person1": {
    name: 'Max',
    age: 10
  },
  'Person2': {
    name: 'John',
    age: 14
  },
  'Person3': {
    name: 'Anna',
    age: 20
  },
  'Person4': {
    name: 'Jim',
    age: 11
  }
};

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
  return { key: key, obj: obj[key] }; 
}).sort((a, b) => {
  return (a.obj.name > b.obj.name)? 1 : (a.obj.name < b.obj.name)? -1 : 0;
}).reduce((res, item) => {
  res[item.key] = item.obj;
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```